# Rsyslog collect logs from different timezones

Tags: timezone, rsyslog

Im using rsyslog on server to collect logs from remote hosts.

**Collect server config:**

```
# timedatectl
               Local time: Wed 2022-04-27 16:02:43 MSK
           Universal time: Wed 2022-04-27 13:02:43 UTC
                 RTC time: n/a                        
                Time zone: Europe/Moscow (MSK, +0300) 
System clock synchronized: yes                        
              NTP service: inactive                   
          RTC in local TZ: no
# cat /etc/rsyslog.d/20_external.conf
$CreateDirs on
$PreserveFQDN on

# provides UDP syslog reception
module(load="imudp")
input(type="imudp" port="514")

# provides TCP syslog reception
module(load="imtcp")
input(type="imtcp" port="514")

template(
      name="external"
      type="string"
      string="/var/log/external/%HOSTNAME%/%syslogfacility-text%.%programname%.%syslogseverity-text%.log"
)

action(
      type="omfile"
      dirCreateMode="0775"
      FileCreateMode="0644"
      dynaFile="external"
)
```

**On remote host**

```
# timedatectl
               Local time: Wed 2022-04-27 13:04:03 UTC
           Universal time: Wed 2022-04-27 13:04:03 UTC
                 RTC time: n/a                        
                Time zone: UTC (UTC, +0000)           
System clock synchronized: yes                        
              NTP service: inactive                   
          RTC in local TZ: no
# cat /etc/rsyslog.d/10-external.conf 
*.* @rserver
# logger "hello, local time $(date)"
```

**And get on rsyslogserver:**

```
cat  /var/log/external/ruser.home.xmu/user.root.notice.log
2022-04-27T13:07:06+03:00 ruser.home.xmu root: hello, local time 2022-04-27T13:07:06 UTC
# date
2022-04-27T16:08:56 MSK
```

**What i can do for change time zone settings for some remote hosts on collect-server?**

When i reserch incedents from all servers the time does not match in logs. I want the time on the collector in the logs to be in his time zone.

```
2022-04-27T16:07:06+03:00 ruser.home.xmu root: hello, local time 2022-04-27T13:07:06 UTC
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem and what you're trying to achieve. Do you want to change the time zone of the **server**? Or do you want to change the timestamp that **rsyslog** uses?

Comment: When i reserch incedents from all servers the time does not match in logs.
I want the time on the collector in the logs to be in his time zone.




2022-04-27T16:07:06+03:00 ruser.home.xmu root: hello, local time 2022-04-27T13:07:06 UTC

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar problem recently. I think the simplest way to synchronize data coming from multiple sources is to use UTC timestamps everywhere, this way you avoid any timezone and summer time/winter time problems.

I think the problem here (and the problem I had) is that the syslog ouput uses the `rfc3164` format which does not include the timezone information:

```
<6>Feb 28 12:00:00 192.168.0.1 fluentd[11111]: [error] Hello!
```

There's no way of knowing at what time that message actually happened without the timezone information. Since rsyslog version 8.18.0 what you can do though is define custom rsyslog templates that print the timestamps in UTC. If you use UTC everywhere you don't need that timestamp information anymore.

I'm sending my logs to fluentd, I use the following configuration in my `rsyslog.conf` file on my hosts:

```
template(
  name="UTCTraditionalForwardFormat"
  type="string"
  string="<%PRI%>%TIMESTAMP:::date-utc% %HOSTNAME% %syslogtag:1:32%%msg:::sp-if-no-1st-sp%%msg%"
)

*.* action(
  type="omfwd"
  Target="10.5.0.9"
  Port="5145"
  Protocol="udp"
  Template="UTCTraditionalForwardFormat"
)
```

The `UTCTraditionalForwardFormat` here is the same as the default template `RSYSLOG_TraditionalForwardFormat` ([rsyslog templates](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/templates.html)) but with an added `:::date-utc` to the `TIMESTAMP` property.

On your rsyslog that collects logs, looking at [the input module's doc](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/modules/imudp.html) there an experimental parameter `DefaultTZ` which should let you define the source timezone, something like this should work (I haven't tested):

```
input(
  type="imudp"
  port="514"
  DefaultTZ="+00:00"
)
```

Assuming this `DefaultTZ` parameter works, this should work regardless of your hosts timezone.

Little word about `fluentd`, the fluentd syslog module also accepts the `rfc5424` message format which does encode timezone information. I decided not to go this way though because rsyslog default templates does not seem to have a real `rfc5424` version (the `RSYSLOG_SyslogProtocol23Format` template is very close to the `rfc5424`, but I don't know *how close*).

Answer (score 1):

You can define the timezone in rsyslog on the client - which in my opinion is the cleaner solution.

In `/etc/rsyslog.conf` do the following:

Comment/remove the current template

```
# Use default timestamp format
#$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat
```

Then add the timezone, as well as a custom log template:

```
timezone(id="MSK" offset="+03:00")

# Custom time format
$template myTemplate,"%timegenerated% %HOSTNAME% %syslogtag%%msg%\n"
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate myTemplate
```

---

However, if you can't access the remote client which is sending the logs, it's possible to use the timestamp when the log was received on the server.

```
$template myTemplate,"%timegenerated% %HOSTNAME% %syslogtag%%msg%\n"

ruleset(name="myRuleset"){
    $ActionFileDefaultTemplate myTemplate
    # Do some other stuff
}

module(load="imtcp")
input(type="imtcp" port="5000" ruleset="myRuleset")

module(load="imudp")
input(type="imudp" port="5000" ruleset="myRuleset")
```

---

NOTE: Don't forget to restart the rsyslog service after applying the changes.

```
sudo service rsyslog restart
```

---

EDIT:

Creating a template using the *advanced syntax* would look like the following:

```
template (name="myTemplate" type="string"
    string="%timegenerated% %HOSTNAME% %syslogtag%%msg%\n")
```

The `string` is the actual **template** of the messages that should be logged, **not the destination** to which the messages should be logged.

Comment: add timezone(id="MSK" offset="+03:00"). No changes

`2022-04-29T11:42:56+03:00 ruser.home.xmu root: hello, local time 2022-04-29T11:42:56 UTC`

Comment: And i can't change timezone on athers servers. Systems must set in local zones.

Comment: Did you restart the service after modifying `/etc/rsyslog.conf`?

Comment: Yes. Restart. Screen = https://bp.salo.vip/wscRs7cd/+inline

Comment: Create a modified template as described in the answer. I've updated the answer so it includes an example with the "advanced syntax". 

Also please [don't post links to pictures](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question#:~:text=Images%20require%20more%20bandwidth%20than,byte%20and%20every%20millisecond%20count.) on Stack Overflow.

Comment: timegenerated not same as timegenerated:

https://www.rsyslog.com/what-is-the-difference-between-timereported-and-timegenerated/

...

“timegenerated” is always the time when rsyslog generated the message object on the local machine. That actually means it is the time when the message was received (either via the oscall layer or on some inputs based on information the OS provides).

...

Comment: Yes that's correct, it would be the time of the system on the receiving end. But that's how you could create a timestamp independent of the client sending the logs. I know that this wouldn't be a very nice solution.